# Cannot get the response because of the custom header value

Tags: http, next.js, header, http-headers, nestjs

I have faced very weird issue. Here is my Next.js function, that sends request to Nest.js API.

```
// src/services/logout.service.ts

import React from 'react';

import { ApiClient } from '@api-client';
import { ExceptionHandler } from '@exception-handler';
import { LogoutRequest, LogoutResponse } from '@services/logout/logout.interface';

export const useLogoutService = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const logout = async (payload: LogoutRequest)
    : Promise<LogoutResponse> => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const { data } = await ApiClient.get<LogoutResponse>('/auth/logout', {
        headers: { 'x-access-token': `Bearer ${payload.token}` }
      });

      return data;
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw ExceptionHandler(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { logout, loading };
};
```

I can tell, that `req.headers['x-access-token']` is not an empty string, I have checked that.

```
// src/pages/api/logout.ts

import { AxiosError } from 'axios';
import { serialize } from 'cookie';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

import { Api } from '@api';


export default async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) => {
  try {
    const { data, headers } = await Api.get('/user/logout', {
      // If I comment out this line, everything will work
      headers: { 'x-access-token': req.headers['x-access-token'] }
    });

    if (headers['set-cookie']) {
      res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize(
        '_rt', '', {
          path: '/',
          httpOnly: true,
          maxAge: -1
        }
      ));
    }

    return res.json(data);
  } catch (error: any) {
    return res
      .status((error as AxiosError).response?.status as number)
      .json((error as AxiosError).response?.data);
  }
};
```

You see this line, where I pass headers value in order to forward it to back-end - `headers: { 'x-access-token': req.headers['x-access-token'] }`. There is where problem starts. If I have this line, I just have pending in the browser all the time and I don't get any response, but when I comment it out, everthing works perfectly fine.

Here is logout function on the back-end:

```
@UseGuards(JwtGuard)
  @Get('logout')
  async logout(@UserDecorator() userId: string, @Res() res) {
    console.log('userId', userId)
    return { message: 'success' };
  }
```

This console.log also works fine, but still no response. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found an issue, it about back-end:

```
@UseGuards(JwtGuard)
  @Get('logout')
  // Problem is this res, because of it, return gets "ignored"
  async logout(@UserDecorator() userId: string, @Res() res) {
    console.log('userId', userId)
    return { message: 'success' };
  }
```

I removed this `@Res() res` and it started working.